# How get os and device info in Windows Runtime JavaScript App?

Tags: javascript, windows, win-universal-app, version, device

I'm using analytics to better understand user profile. I need some information like OS version and device info (not sensors info but manufacturer, phone model etc).

I did not find anything obvious in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211377.aspx).

My app is a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) JavaScript Application

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Dn960162.aspx

Comment: perfect @theB .If you write it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the information you're looking for is in the [`Windows.System.Profile.AnalyticsInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Dn960162.aspx) class.

More information is available through the [`Windows.System.Profile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.profile) namespace.